# 3 divs with percentage width

Tags: css, html

Lets say, I have div which is 65% in width, inside that div I need to create 3 more divs which are in same line, same size but size should be in % and there should be 10px gap between side divs and center div. Any suggestions?

So far I have the following code:

```
    <div style="width: 65%; margin: 0 auto; text-align:left; margin-bottom: 10px;">
<div style="float:left; margin-right: 10px;">1</div>
<div style="float:left; margin-right: 10px;">2</div>
<div style="float:left;">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bit more HTML, but it's worked quite well for me.

**HTML**

```
<div id="hold">
    <div class="innerHold"><div class="inner col1">
        Column won
    </div></div>
    <div class="innerHold"><div class="inner col2">
        Col Two
    </div></div>
    <div class="innerHold"><div class="inner col3">
        Col 3
    </div></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#hold{
    width: 65%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.innerHold{
    float: left;
    width:33.33333%;
    /* make sure left/right margins or left/right padding are 0px here
            - it'll mess with the width otherwise*/
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
}
.inner{
    /* Here set your columns padding, borders, and margin 
            - or in the class names as I do below */
    margin:0px;
}
.col1, .col2{
    margin-right:10px;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/NR2kX/1/

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest solution I can think of: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seE2F/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="small">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="small">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="small">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -o-box-sizing:border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 65%;
  height: 300px;
}

.small {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  padding-right: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

.small:last-child {
  padding: 0;
}
```

I have used

```
box-sizing: border-box
```

to include padding in width declared in percentages. I've also used `:last-child` selector to remove padding from last element. Make sure to check browser support for [`box-sizing`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing)

Answer (score 1):

This will mean that your quoted width of 33% will include all padding etc and there is no need to alter the width as border box accounts for this .... here is some browser compatibility options as well!

```
   box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /* Safari */
```

[Here is a helpful link on box sizing!](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading right, you want the 3 divs to be 33% of its parent div. 33.3% x 3 = 100% (close enough) but if you want padding in you have to reduce the percentage of the divs. for example having the 3 divs at 30% (30% x 3 = 90%) allows you to have 10% le-way, so you can each div to have 3.33% of padding or however it is you want to allocate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Done this in such way:

```
    <div style="width: 65%; margin: 0 auto; text-align:left; margin-bottom: 10px;">
<div style="float:left; width: 30%; background-color: #FFFFFF;">1</div>
<div style="float:left; width: 5%;">.</div>
<div style="float:left; width: 30%; background-color: #FFFFFF;">2</div>
<div style="float:left; width: 5%;">.</div>
<div style="float:left; width: 30%; background-color: #FFFFFF;">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would this work with a fixed-width (of 10px) for the spacers?

Comment: It doesn't really matter so much for me. Still in this solution I have a problem with spacer divs, they need a symbol inside to be displayed...

Comment: Try using a non-breakable space instead. Same as a normal space, but it wont collapse. `&nbsp;`

Answer (score -1):

try this not the perfect but maybe this help

html

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box noMarginRight">3</div>
</div>
```

css

```
 .wrapper {
    float:left;
    width:65%;
    background-color:#555;
}
.box {
    float:left;
    width:31.4%;
    background-color:#000;
    margin:0 10px 0 0;
}
.noMarginRight {margin-right:0 !important}
```

working [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/seE2F/3/)